# DLL on server is "in use" - cannot replace it

Tags: c#, iis, dll

I am publishing a ASP.NET website to an IIS web server.

On the server I also have a small C# EXE (debug-related) that uses a certain DLL of that website. The EXE is opened from client computers via SMB. The DLL was added to the EXE project as a "Reference" in "Solution Explorer".

Sometimes, after debugging with that exe, when I try to publish the fixed dll, I get an error related to that DLL with the message:

> bin\website.dll: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I can say with confidence that the small EXE is not running anywhere when the error occurs, but I guess that the DLL is not unloaded directly on close, or possibly a network problem causes the handle to hang around even though the program is already closed on the client computer.

How would I find which of these two is true, or whether it is something else?
(Can I somehow force the EXE to unload the DLL when closing?)

Comment: May be dll is used by website? You can restart pool ot IIS to unload it. Other way is make changes in web.config - this action unloads website also.

Comment: Using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) you can find which process is using the DLL through the [search](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-find-out-which-windows-process-using-file.htm) functionality

Comment: @General-Doomer IIS creates a copy of the DLL and works with that copy only. The issue does never occur until the EXE has been started, but it does not stop when the EXE is closed again.

Comment: Have you used TaskMan to make sure the EXE is removed from memory and not just running in the background?

Comment: Are you sure no client computers inadvertently have the `.exe` open?